# Install a Haskell package directly from a git repository?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

`stack` allows one to define git repositories as packages using the `stack.yaml` file. Is it possible to do something like the following, directly via command-line:

```
stack install --resolver=lts-12.1 git@github.com:saurabhnanda/some-repo.git
```

**Use-case:** Install a command-line tool that I have written during a `docker` build process. I want to avoid cloning the repo *and then* building it. Is there a short-hand for this?

Comment: Well, you could `git clone git@github.com:foo/bar.git && cd ./bar && stack install`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin that's the backup plan :) Was wondering if a shortcut is already available in `stack`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

**New solution**

Right after submitting the answer I thought of a separate solution.

You can create a custom `custom-snapshot.yaml` file in your repository that extends some existing snapshot, such as [lts-15.3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/15/3.yaml) for example. Add your package to it in a similar way you would add it to the `stack.yaml`.
And the point to it when installing the tool:

```
$ stack install --resolver https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saurabhnanda/my-cool-tool/master/custom-snapshot.yaml my-cool-tool
```

or [even shorter](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/#snapshot-location):

```
$ stack install --resolver github:saurabhnanda/my-cool-tool:custom-snapshot.yaml my-cool-tool
```

*Disclaimer* -  I have not tried it, but in theory it should work.

**Old solution**

I don't think you can do it at cli without `stack.yaml`

So two options are:

- either create a temporary project with `stack new` add your repository to the `stack.yaml`
- or add the same information to into the global `stack.yaml`, location of which can be found programmatically:

```sh
$ stack path --config-location
/home/saurabhnanda/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
```

and add this to `extra-deps`:

```yaml
- github: saurabhnanda/some-repo
  commit: master
  subdirs:
    - my-cool-tool
```

After that running `stack install my-cool-tool` should work as normal.

I don't think it would be too hard too write up a Haskell script that could do one of those two solutions for you and host as a gist that can be `curl`ed and executed on demand with `stack`.

Comment: that seems like a very cool workaround. However, I can't get the following to work - `stack install --resolver=github:saurabhnanda/aws-lambda-packager:snapshot.yml aws-lambda-packager`, while the following works: `stack install --resolver=<local-path>/aws-lambda-packager/snapshot.yml aws-lambda-packager`

Comment: basically referring to the `snapshot.yml` file from github seems to give a weird error, while referring to a local file works.

Comment: Try fixing the commit sha in the snapshot. Error I get is that stack can't find the cabal file

Comment: Are you getting the following error as well? `fatal: Could not parse object 'd3312736a38f7b93f87c313a8fb9c0798938b403'` -- Strangely, that commit _does_ exist at https://github.com/saurabhnanda/aws-lambda-packager/commit/d3312736a38f7b93f87c313a8fb9c0798938b403

Comment: The commit you specified does not have a cabal file, that's why you are probably having an issue. Also, make sure you are on the latest stack